# Why ContourPlot3D plot is in yxz system?

Tags: plotting

I was trying to explain to someone projection of points in space. I used ContourPlot3D and plotted the planes x=1, y=1 and z=1 to show that the point (1,1,1) is the point where these three planes intersect. The problem is Mathematica plots the plane in the yxz coordinate system instead of the traditional xyz coordinate system. Here's the simple code I used:

```
Manipulate[
ContourPlot3D[{x == a, y == b, z == c}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10,10}, {z, -10, 10},
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Mesh -> 0], {{a, 2, "x"}, -10, 10},
{{b, 2, "y"}, -10, 10}, {{c, 2, "z"}, -10, 10}]
```

So, when I try to change a, the x plane shifts but because the coordinate system used is the yxz, it appears as if the y plane is shifted. This causes confusion because the guy I'm trying to help has xyz system fixed in his mind.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I want this system:
[image: xyz]

but Mathematica is giving me this:

[image: yxz]

Comment: Do you mean why does it use a right-handed instead of a left-handed [orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions)?  (Or could it be the view-point?)

Comment: Yes. Its the system used; not the viewpoint!

Comment: The right-handed system is the traditional xyz system in my experience (mathematics, US), but I'm aware that might not be universal.  [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+coordinate+system&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=JW1ZVLTuE4aoyAT4mYLgDQ&ved=0CCcQsAQ&biw=1036&bih=790) shows quite a mix....

Comment: Mathematica uses a right-handed coordinate system, compare `Graphics3D[{Green, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], Red, 
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
  Axes -> True]` to your first (right handed) figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your problem:

[image]

As you can see, the $x,y,z$ axes are in a right-handed coordinate system, in contrast to what you describe, and in accordance with Szabolcs comment.

I think you're probably getting tricked by the fact that when it initially is displayed, it has the negative axis pointing towards the camera. However, if you pay attention to the axes, you'll notice that they're right-handed, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Can you label the planes. Is the brown plane, the plane x=a or y=a ??

Comment: @user47181: The brown plane is $x$, which you can tell because it corresponds to the bar which is most positive (see the `Manipulate` bars above the graph to see why). Unfortunately I'm not sure it's possible to label `ContourPlot3D` axes (I'm not sure why?).

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It's because (I think) the OP has set the AxesOrigin to {0, 0, 0}.  The labels are obscured by the planes.  Remove that option and the axes and labels will appear on the box.

Comment: I didn't see the slider bar. My bad. I think I'm getting tricked by the default display. It makes one feel stupid asking the question. I didnt notice the negative sign because I disabled the ticks in the plot I'm using. Is there a way to change the orientation the plot by default such that positive x, y and z are toward the viewer ?

Comment: @user47181: "It makes one feel stupid asking the question." No, it's stupid that Mathematica has the default orientation in that direction. There is a way to change the default orientation, namely by adding the setting `ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}` (which works for any 3D graphics, not just `ContourPlot3D`).

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Your last statement is wrong. `ViewPoint` does not help to change the coordinates system from right- to left-handed. Citation: "
ViewPoint is an option for Graphics3D and related functions which gives the point in space from which three-dimensional objects are to be viewed. " See this: https://i.imgur.com/IEmc4Cq.png and that https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157876/how-to-exchange-axes-in-a-3d-plot-from-right-to-left-handed-coordinate-system.