# How to exchange axes in a 3D plot (from right- to left-handed coordinate system)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have, as an example, a 3D plot showing some data:

```
data = {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 80, 0}, {0, 0, 60}}

ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.04]}, BoxRatios -> {100, 80, 60}, 
  Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 80}, {0, 60}}]
```

[image: normal]

This corresponds to a [right-handed coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandedCoordinateSystem.html). (See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64902/why-contourplot3d-plot-is-in-yxz-system).)

**I want to exchange the $y$ and $z$ axes** to switch to a [left-handed coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Left-HandedCoordinateSystem.html).

Manually, I can do:

```
datanew = {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 60, 0}, {0, 0, 80}};

ListPointPlot3D[datanew, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large]}, BoxRatios -> {100, 60, 80}, 
  Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "y"},
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 60}, {0, 80}}]
```

**Does a built-in solution exist to exchange two axes**, whereby the $y$ and $z$ data are exchanged as well as the axes labels?

[image: exchanged]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lpp3d = ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.04]}, 
   BoxRatios -> {100, 80, 60}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 80}, {0, 60}}]

newoptions= Flatten[{(# -> (# /. Options[lpp3d])[[{1,3,2}]])&/@ 
   {BoxRatios, AxesLabel, BoxRatios, PlotRange}, 
   FilterRules[Options[lpp3d], {Boxed, Axes, ViewProjection, AxesEdge}]}];

ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, {1,3,2}]], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.04]}, newoptions]
```

[image]

Alternatively,, post-process to change the graphics primitives and options:

```
f = #[[{1, 3, 2}]]&;
lpp3d /. { Point[x_] :> Point[f/@x], 
  Rule[o: Alternatives[BoxRatios, AxesLabel, BoxRatios, PlotRange], v_] :> Rule[o, f @ v]}
```

> same picture

Answer (score 6):

This could be a good place for some pattern matching. To switch the data around:

```
data = {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 80, 0}, {0, 0, 60}}; 
datanew = data[[#]] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, z, y} & /@ Range[Length[data]]

{{100, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 80}, {0, 60, 0}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to set `ViewVertical` appropriately:

```
data = {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 80, 0}, {0, 0, 60}};
ListPointPlot3D[data, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
                AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {100, 80, 60}, 
                PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 80}, {0, 60}}, 
                PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04], ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
                ViewVertical -> UnitVector[3, 2]]
```

[image: flipped axes]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution from Wolfram:

```
data = {{100, 0, 0}, {0, 80, 0}, {0, 0, 60}};

rhListPointPlot3D[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[ListPointPlot3D]] := 
 Module[{newDat = data /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> {x, z, y}}, 
 ListPointPlot3D[newDat, opts]]

rhListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large]}, BoxRatios -> {100, 60, 80}, 
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "y"}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 60}, {0, 80}}]
```

[image]